# how to enable the customview controller with view after dismiss Second viewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controller
[imag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcOmY.png)
1.first view controller is main and second is CustomAlertviw controller 
main view controller is like above image, when I click continues am showing the customalertview controller, like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVrqR.png). when click the enter pin button I have to dismiss view contoller and show the view controller with uiview on main view controller but tried, it's showing the view controller, there one more custom view is not showing it crashing my app

main view code

```
    @IBAction func backButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let myAlert = UIStoryboard(name: "CustomAlertview", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertViewController") as? CustomAlertViewController
            myAlert?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
            myAlert?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
         self.present(myAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

Customalertview controller 
  @IBAction func enterPinButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {

       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let myAlert = UIStoryboard(name: "ScanAndPay", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScanAndPayDetailsEntryViewController") as? ScanAndPayDetailsEntryViewController
        myAlert?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        myAlert?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        self.present(myAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        myAlert.valuespass()
    }


inside main view controller one function calling from the customalrerview 

func  valuespass()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.authType = 1
            self.authStatus = false
            print("this is calling")
            self.pinStatusLabel.text = "Please enter a 4-digit Security PIN"
}
```

when I am calling this function from the custom alert view application is crashing and showing the hread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value this error. how to can show the all information after dismissing the custom view controller.

Comment: Add `delay` between `every preset new Controller`

Comment: @AmirKhan tq for replay I can try!

Comment: let me know if you are still having any issue.

Comment: @AmirKhan still same issue, when I click the password button it was not loading the pinStatusLabel.text  because it was on my custom view on view controller

Comment: Are you using `Delegate` to pass data?

Comment: As I can see you dismiss `CustomAlertview` before presenting `ScanAndPay`, That cause the issue.

Comment: if not dismiss the view is showing on the viewcontroller

Comment: Yes I got your point. Let me dig into this and solve the issue for you.

Comment: when I dismiss view controller i have show one view on to the main view controller and some text fields but when it tried it was crashing

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done. present `ScanAndPay` from `FirstView` instead of `CustomAlertview`.

I have done using `Delegate` as I think it will be fit in this scenario. Follow below steps -

**Step 1:**

In **FirstViewController** ,

Add - `CustomAlertviewDelegate` something like this -

```
  class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CustomAlertviewDelegate {
```

Now replace your `backButtonClicked` method -

```
  @IBAction func backButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let myAlert = UIStoryboard(name: "CustomAlertview", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertViewController") as? CustomAlertViewController
        myAlert?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        myAlert?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        myAlert.delegate = self
        self.present(myAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```

Add a new `Delegate` method of `CustomAlertviewDelegate` -

```
func ScanAndPayView(){
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
           let myAlert = UIStoryboard(name: "ScanAndPay", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScanAndPayDetailsEntryViewController") as? ScanAndPayDetailsEntryViewController
           myAlert?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
           myAlert?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
           self.present(myAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Now time for **CustomAlertview** ,

Add protocol for delegate top of the Class -

```
protocol CustomAlertviewDelegate: class {

   func ScanAndPayView()
}

class CustomAlertview: UIViewController{
  weak var delegate : CustomAlertviewDelegate!
  ...
  override func viewDidLoad() { // Rest of your code
}
```

Now time to dismiss current view controller and notify `FirstViewController` for presenting `ScanAndPay view Controller` -

```
@IBAction func enterPinButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
   delegate.ScanAndPayView()
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Hope it will help you to achieve what you want.